# spark, kafka integration issue: object kafka is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am receiving error while building my spark application (scala) in IntelliJ IDE. 
It is a simple application with uses Kafka Stream for further processing. I have added all the jars and the IDE does not show any unresolved import or code statements.

However, when I try to build the artifact, I get two errors stating that 
Error:(13, 35) object kafka is not a member of package

```
org.apache.spark.streaming
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils

Error:(35, 60) not found: value KafkaUtils
    val messages: ReceiverInputDStream[(String, String)] = KafkaUtils.createStream(streamingContext,zkQuorum,"myGroup",topics)
```

I have seen similar questions but most of the ppl complain about this issue while submitting to spark. However, I one step behind that and merely building the jar file which would be submitted ultimately to spark. On top I am using IntelliJ IDE and a bit new to spark and scala; lost here.

Below is the snapshot of the IntelliJ Error
[IntelliJ Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1hbP.png)

Thanks

Omer

Comment: Can you specify the versions of Spark and Kafka. and are you sure that spark-streaming-kafka jar is added in your pom.xml?

Comment: Its kafka 0.10 and spark 1.6.2. I am using SBT so not sure about pom.xml and whole application is built using IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you need to add `spark-streaming-kafka-K.version-Sc.version.jar` to your pom.xml and as well as your spark lib directory.

Comment: I am still new to this area so I am not if pom.xml will come into play if we use maven and in my case, we have SBT.

Comment: I am still new to this area but I think pom.xml will come into play  only if we use maven and in my case, we have SBT. 
Btw I managed to build the jar through IntelliJ by providing all the Jars in one folder which I copied from each module (spark and kafka -- from hortonworks dsomehow. But I am still not sure why IntelliJ did not figure it out. I tried the SBT.build solution mentioned in other posts while submitting to spark but even that did not work and I had to specify jar files folder in the command to run it. Its quite cumbersome to specify jar files path. Any better solution ? Thanks.